# How do I set a program to launch at startup

Tags: c#, windows

I have a small application with a `CheckBox` option that the user can set if they want the app to start with Windows.

My question is how do I actually set the app to run at startup.

ps: I'm using C# with .NET 2.0.

Comment: If your application does something time consuming or resource intensive at startup like checking for updates on the internet, you might want to consider implementing a timer so that your program runs a bit after startup. One of my pet peeves is the dozen or so programs on my computer that drag everything to a crawl as they all check for updates at startup (yeah I'm especially looking at you, iTunes and Java).

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Several options, in order of preference:

1. Add it to the current user's Startup folder. This requires the least permissions for your app to run, and gives the user the most control and feedback of what's going on. The down-side is it's a little more difficult determining whether to show the checkbox already checked next time they view that screen in your program.
2. Add it to the `HKey_Current_User\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` registry key. The only problem here is it requires write access to the registry, which isn't always available.
3. Create a Scheduled Task that triggers on User Login
4. Add it to the `HKey_Local_Machine\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` registry key.  The only problem here is it requires write access to the registry, which isn't always available.
5. Set it up as a windows service. Only do this if you *really* mean it, *and* you know for sure you want to run this program for *all* users on the computer.

This answer is older now. Since I wrote this, Windows 10 was released, which changes how the Start Menu folders work... including the `Startup` folder. It's not yet clear to me how easy it is to just add or remove a file in that folder without also referencing the internal database Windows uses for these locations.

Comment: there are directories and registry keys for the current user and for all users. decide what you need for your application.

Comment: Thanks everyone for responding so quickly. Joel I went with you option 2.

Comment: Windows Service yes, but you need to run the application with Impersonate As User option. If not it will launch the program only once and in the System session.

Comment: For number 2, what kind of permissions are we looking at? I tried with maximum UAC on Win 7, and it warned of nothing.

Comment: @Joel in what scenarios you dont have write access to HKCU? I think even a Guest user can write this registry hive

Answer (score 154):

Thanks to everyone for responding so fast.
Joel, I used your option 2 and added a registry key to the "Run" folder of the current user.
Here's the code I used for anyone else who's interested.

```
    using Microsoft.Win32;
    private void SetStartup()
    {
        RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
            ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

        if (chkStartUp.Checked)
            rk.SetValue(AppName, Application.ExecutablePath);
        else
            rk.DeleteValue(AppName,false);            

    }
```

Comment: What is the chkStartUp variable?

Comment: I know I am late, @fernado Santiago but it is his checkbox that allows the user to add or remove the program from the startup.

Comment: This is not helpful for me, it gives me permissions error. is there any way i can manually take permissions and then release them?

Comment: what is `AppName` ?

Comment: @mrid AppName is just a placeholder. Essentially it is of string format. Just replace AppName with "The name of your application".

Comment: @JamshaidK. To 'manually take permission' you would run the application with administrator privileges, which will give it the permissions it needs.

Answer (score 22):

Here is all way to add your program to startup for Windows Vista, 7, 8, 10

> - **File path**
>
> `C:\Users\Bureau Briffault\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs\Startup` (Visible from task manager, Running on current
>   user login success, No admin privileges required)
>
> `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs\Startup` (Visible from task manager, Running on all user
>   login success, Admin privileges required)

---

> - **Registry path**
>
> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`
>   (Visible from task manager, Running on current user login success, No
>   admin privileges required)
>
> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce`
>   (Not visible from task manager, Running on current user login success,
>   Running for one login time, No admin privileges required)
>
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`
>   (Visible from task manager, Running on all user login success, Admin
>   privileges required)
>
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce`
>   (Not visible from task manager, Running on all user login success,
>   Running for one login time, Admin privileges required)

---

> - **Task scheduler**
>
> `Microsoft.Win32.Taskscheduler.dll` (Not visible from task manager,
>   Running on windows boot, Running as admin, Admin privileges required)

Comment: i was using this to start a weblogic server and taks scheduler seemed like the best way to go since we didnt want to log in to windows to have the server started. however the thing to notice is that the processes were visible in task manager while running as admin, and also no `UI` was shown. but server still ran fine. ( windows server 2016 )

Comment: @OP You forgot an option -- creating a Windows service that launches the program at startup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15719678/2441655

Answer (score 16):

It`s a so easy solution:

To Add

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
key.SetValue("Your Application Name", Application.ExecutablePath);
```

To Remove

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
key.DeleteValue("Your Application Name", false);
```

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Xepher Dotcom's answer, folder path to Windows Startup should be coded that way:

```
var Startup = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Add application to Startup of windows
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="appName"></param>
    /// <param name="path"></param>
    public static void AddStartup(string appName, string path)
    {
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
            ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
        {
            key.SetValue(appName, "\"" + path + "\"");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove application from Startup of windows
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="appName"></param>
    public static void RemoveStartup(string appName)
    {
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
            ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
        {
            key.DeleteValue(appName, false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a registry entry in "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", just be aware that it may work differently on Vista. Your setting might get "virtualized" because of UAC.

Answer (score 3):

If an application is designed to start when Windows starts (as opposed to when a user logs in), your only option is to involve a Windows Service. Either write the application as a service, or write a simple service that exists only to launch the application.

Writing services can be tricky, and can impose restrictions that may be unacceptable for your particular case. One common design pattern is a front-end/back-end pair, with a service that does the work and an application front-end that communicates with the service to display information to the user.

On the other hand, if you just want your application to start on user login, you can use methods 1 or 2 that Joel Coehoorn listed.

Comment: You can use the NSSM utility to run an arbitrary application as a service.

Answer (score 3):

if you using wpf, the "ExecutablePath" don't work. So i made a code that work on wpf too.

```cs
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
{
    key.SetValue(
        "AutoStart.exe", 
        "\"" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "\""
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found adding a shortcut to the startup folder to be the easiest way for me. I had to add a reference to "Windows Script Host Object Model" and "Microsoft.CSharp" and then used this code:

```
IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell shell = new IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell();
string shortcutAddress = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup) + @"\MyAppName.lnk";
System.Reflection.Assembly curAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress);
shortcut.Description = "My App Name";
shortcut.WorkingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
shortcut.TargetPath = curAssembly.Location;
shortcut.IconLocation = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"MyIconName.ico";
shortcut.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the win32 class in the Microsoft namespace

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
 {
            key.SetValue("aldwin", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath + "\"");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Important addition to other's answers using `Application.ExecutablePath`: if one of the folders containing your exe contains some strange chars (like mine had C# name) then `Application.ExecutablePath` will return path with different slashes which will result in it not working.

`Application.ExecutablePath.Replace('/', '\\')` is more appropriate

Answer (score -3):

**Add an app to run automatically at startup in Windows 10**

Step 1: Select the Windows **Start** button and scroll to find the app you want to run at startup.

Step 2: Right-click the app, select **More**, and then select **Open file location**. This opens the location where the shortcut to the app is saved. If there isn't an option for **Open file location**, it means the app can't run at startup.

[image]

Step 3: With the file location open, press the **Windows logo key + R**, type **shell:startup**, then select **OK**. This opens the **Startup** folder.

[image]

Step 4: Copy and paste or Create the shortcut to the app from the file location to the **Startup** folder.

[image]