# Create Windows service from executable

Tags: windows, windows-services

Is there any quick way to, given an executable file, create a Windows service that, when started, launches it?

Comment: [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890/en-us) is Microsoft's instructions about how to achieve this.

Answer (score 632, accepted):

To create a Windows Service from an executable, you can use `sc.exe`:

```
sc.exe create <new_service_name> binPath= "<path_to_the_service_executable>"
```

You must have quotation marks around the actual `exe` path, and a space after the `binPath=`.

[More information on the `sc` command can be found in Microsoft KB251192](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192).

Note that it will not work for just any executable: the executable must be a Windows Service ([i.e. implement ServiceMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685138(v=vs.85).aspx)). When registering a non-service executable as a service, you'll get the following error upon trying to start the service:

> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

There are tools that can create a Windows Service from arbitrary, non-service executables, see the other answers for examples of such tools.

Comment: you'll (almost certainly) have to run the command prompt as Administrator in order for this command to work

Comment: The path also needs to be the fully qualified path - I could not get my service to start by using a relative path.

Comment: the space after `binpath=` along with having to surround the executable path with double quotes is totally wrong, at least for windows 10. the quoting is required if and only if the path contains special characters like whitespace. also, casing (lowe/upper/mixed-case) doesn't matter anywhere, in variable names too, and `displayname="my service"` is another goodie to pass on the commandline while creating a service to view as the first row (`Name`) at `services.msc`.

Comment: The space after `binPath=` was required for me on Windows 7 but not on Windows 10

Comment: As this answer concedes, this only works for exe designed to be Windows services.

Comment: when i start the service `sc start PC-Service` i got this error. `[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:

The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.`

Comment: down voted since it does not fulfill 'given an executable file'!

Answer (score 344):

Use NSSM( **the non-Sucking Service Manager** ) to run a .BAT or any .EXE file as a service.

http://nssm.cc/

- **Step 1**: Download NSSM
- **Step 2**: Install your sevice with `nssm.exe install [serviceName]`
- **Step 3**: This will open a GUI which you will use to locate your executable

Comment: Best service manager ever. I even managed to get PlexWatch to install as a service using NSSM.

Comment: does this set is a service forever? everytime windows starts the service will start? also how can I do this without user interaction? a script or code of some sort?

Comment: This is absolutely great, I wish I could accept this answer instead of the first one, :-(

Comment: I can run Dropbox as a service on the server. Absolutely a non-sucking tool!

Comment: Do the exe file must be a windows service project, to be able to work with nssm or it can be a normal exe file ?, because when i use the nssm start [servicename] it showing error like, windows service can't run from command prompt etc.

Comment: @majidarif It works for me. Browsing a few random parts of the source code, it looks alright (no signs of adware or so), and it works perfectly to turn my .cmd script into a service that starts on boot!

Comment: Site works, and successfully ran a batch file on Windows 10. Magnificent.

Comment: Oddly the domain name can not get resolved by 8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1 or any other public DNS; however, Google has the site indexed and shows it in the search result. A little bit more inspection shows, it is caused by their domain's DNS record [`GLUE-BOND-STREET.IAIN.CX`] not getting resolved resolved by any of the public DNS servers. Since their IP is 104.156.51.181, according to whois.domaintools.com, I was able to visit the site by putting the required record in my hosts file to resolve nssm.cc to 104.156.51.181; but is it safe to install software under these circumstances? :/

Comment: Any kind of exe works with nssm tool eighter normal exe or a windows service exe

Comment: the nssm is not that non-sucking, it hides the path, filename and parameters to the executable in the service's details, making it impossible to find the executable and their parameters quickly when analyzing issues or checking command line parameters

Comment: This utility has not been updated since 2017 !

Comment: Great tool, but I need to run and check that is always on, a GUI application. The app is run but it is not visible! In the Task manager I see it in the background processes section. How can I run it as visible application?

Comment: respect to the dewd who wrote this brilliant piece of code!!

Answer (score 116):

Extending (Kevin Tong) answer.

**Step 1:** Download & Unzip [nssm-2.24.zip](http://nssm.cc/release/nssm-2.24.zip)

**Step 2:** From command line type:

`C:\> nssm.exe install [servicename]`

it will open GUI as below (the example is UT2003 server), then simply browse it to: yourapplication.exe

[image]

More information on: https://nssm.cc/usage

Comment: Correct Syntax `nssm.exe install [serviceName]`. This solution works but if you have a GUI Application, it will not work on Win Serever2003. If you later want to remove it, use `nssm.exe remove [youservicename]`

Comment: I'm assuming the reference to nginx is because that's the particular program you want to run as a service?  Until I saw hmd's comment above I thought you were trying to help by implying that nginx was a required dependency to install or something... but then in the GUI it looks like you aren't installing nginx, you're installing an Unreal Tournament server? Just pointing out that the example is inconsistent and potentially misleading. A simple "Suppose you wanted to install nginx as a service, then it would look like this:" would help.

Comment: @flutefreak7 yes `nginx` is not necessary and misleading. The command will work without it as well. It is optional parameter if you want to supply service name from command prompt.

Comment: When I try to use nssm my Windows Forms up is running but form is not shown...Why?

Comment: Its running your application as Windows service, most they are for backend. It could be also that its running as another root / admin username. you have to check it. Also more informations you can check here: https://nssm.cc/usage

Comment: I have already saw that page but could not find anything useful. Yes I know what Windows Service is for but I need form that is why I want to create Windows Forms which runs as service. My application now runs but form is not shown...

Comment: The path to the executable can't contain spaces. So put both nssm and your foo.exe file (etc) in e.g. C:\Programs\nssm and C:\Programs\foo .

Comment: Does any one had the issue  Unexpected status SERVICE_PAUSED in response to START controlhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/39196786/unable-to-start-the-java-application-as-windows-service-using-nssm

Comment: if we want set startup type to "automatic" and Recovery mode to "restart the services", what we should write in command line?

Answer (score 32):

these extras proved useful.. need to be executed as an **Administrator**

```
sc create  <service_name> binpath= "<binary_path>"
sc stop    <service_name>
sc queryex <service_name>
sc delete  <service_name>
```

If your service name has any spaces, enclose in "quotes".

Answer (score 23):

Many existing answers include human intervention at install time. This can be an error-prone process. If you have many executables wanted to be installed as services, the last thing you want to do is to do them manually at install time.

Towards the above described scenario, I created [serman](https://github.com/kflu/serman), a command line tool to install an executable as a service. All you need to write (and only write once) is a simple service configuration file along with your executable. Run

```
serman install <path_to_config_file>
```

will install the service. `stdout` and `stderr` are all logged. For more info, take a look at the [project website](https://github.com/kflu/serman).

A working configuration file is very simple, as demonstrated below. But it also has many useful features such as `<env>` and `<persistent_env>` below.

```xml
<service>
  <id>hello</id>
  <name>hello</name>
  <description>This service runs the hello application</description>

  <executable>node.exe</executable>

  <!-- 
       {{dir}} will be expanded to the containing directory of your 
       config file, which is normally where your executable locates 
   -->
  <arguments>"{{dir}}\hello.js"</arguments>

  <logmode>rotate</logmode>

  <!-- OPTIONAL FEATURE:
       NODE_ENV=production will be an environment variable 
       available to your application, but not visible outside 
       of your application
   -->
  <env name="NODE_ENV" value="production"/>

  <!-- OPTIONAL FEATURE:
       FOO_SERVICE_PORT=8989 will be persisted as an environment
       variable to the system.
   -->
  <persistent_env name="FOO_SERVICE_PORT" value="8989" />
</service>
```

Comment: I tried many, but, this one worked for me without any problems!!!

Answer (score 11):

Same as [Sergii Pozharov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3582179/11942268), but with a PowerShell cmdlet:

```bsh
New-Service -Name "MyService" -BinaryPathName "C:\Path\to\myservice.exe"
```

See [`New-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-service?view=powershell-7) for more customization.

This will only work for executables that already implement the [Windows Services API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it is not limited to the type of executable

Comment: I agree, to me this is the best answer... it also is a programmatic answer. However, to completely answer the OP's question I believe it also needs a line to cover the "and start it" requirement. Start-Service -Name "MyService"

Answer (score 6):

Some of the top answers point to NSSM. This project has not been updated since 2017.

More modern alternative of similar functionality is https://github.com/winsw/winsw/ - contains multiple examples and good docs.

Tip for convenient use, that helped me to set it up faster than NSSM: if you name the `winsw` executable as `myapp.exe` and create XML configuration file `myapp.xml`, you just run `myapp.exe install` and `myapp.exe start` and voila, the service is running.

Answer (score 4):

I've tested a good product for that: [AlwaysUp](https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/). Not free but they have a 30 days trial period so you can give it a try...

Answer (score 4):

I created the cross-platform Service Manager software a few years back so that I could start PHP and other scripting languages as system services on Windows, Mac, and Linux OSes:

https://github.com/cubiclesoft/service-manager

Service Manager is a set of precompiled binaries that install and manage a system service on the target OS using nearly identical command-line options ([source code also available](https://github.com/cubiclesoft/service-manager-src)).  Each platform does have subtle differences but the core features are mostly normalized.

If the child process dies, Service Manager automatically restarts it.

Processes that are started with Service Manager should periodically watch for two notification files to handle restart and reload requests but they don't necessarily have to do that.  Service Manager will force restart the child process if it doesn't respond in a timely fashion to controlled restart/reload requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out my small free utility for service create\edit\delete operations. Here is create example:

Go to Service -> Modify -> Create

[image]

Executable file (google drive): [[Download]](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NXu810HDv3KYe3LcT8q2gZxQ9zLwuI_n)

Source code: [[Download]](https://github.com/devowl/winservicemanager)

Blog post: [[BlogLink]](http://www.devowl.net/2019/08/windows-service-create-edit-delete-servicesmsc.html)

Service editor class: [WinServiceUtils.cs](https://github.com/devowl/winservicemanager/blob/master/WS.Manager/WinService/WinServiceUtils.cs)

Answer (score 1):

Probably all your answers are better, but - just to be complete on the choice of options - I wanted to remind about old, similar method used for years:

**SrvAny** (installed by InstSrv)

as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/create-user-defined-service

Comment: Note that the link to download Resource Kit has been taken down by Microsoft. People have to search for other unofficial downloads or find snapshot in archive.org. Besides, it is expecting0 32bit executable (some 16bit are fine too), the status for 64bit binary is unknown, so people will need to do their own testing.

Comment: I haven't tried this but there is a recreation here: https://github.com/birkett/srvany-ng

Answer (score -1):

I have another method, using the open-source library called Topshelf.
I used it in a c# project, but maybe its available in different programming languages.

Here's a video that explains how to use it a little.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y64L-3HKuP0

The crux of this issue for a lot of people is that you can't install any old .exe as a service unless you use the old method that Tomeg used. I couldn't find the windows nt toolkit that's needed to get that to work.

I was stuck in a corner and this was my way out.