# How to call an already running windows service?

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, service

Is there anyway to call a windows service that's already running or a process to get info? What my goal is to find out if my windows service is an infinite loop or dead lock and see if it responds. So I want to be able to pass an argument from another program to a windows service and want it to to return a string or number.  Is this possible? I can change the windows service to accommodate this. I am thinking of an event or something.

Note: I am not supposed to have the service write to a file or database.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325081/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-via-batch-file-and-start-it-if-it-is-not-r

Comment: You can use ControlService Win32 API to query a service for it's current status. If just knowing status would suffice. And status is basically a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can host a WCF service in your Windows Service which you could call to get status information.

Here are a couple of  links on doing that:

[Can I host a WCF Service in a windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267307/can-i-host-a-wcf-service-in-a-windows-service)

[How to: Host a WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx)