# Getting an Error while opening Window Service

Tags: c#, wcf, service, windows-services

I have created a Windows Service and have also done the Installation of that Service from the Visual studio Developer's Command Prompt as:

```
installutil InvoiceService.exe
```

After that the Service is Installed but I am getting Problem in starting the Service Manually after right clicking into the Task Manager's Services tab.

I am getting the Problem window as:

[image: Prompt while starting the Service]

Help me on this ASAP. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error 5 : Access Denied when starting windows service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267051/error-5-access-denied-when-starting-windows-service)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are some configuration issues in service.

To check in the details go to Event Viewer from start menu and nevigate to following location:

Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application

In the right window pane, you can see the detailed view of exceptions logs.