# Running a process that interacts with SQL Server from a Windows Service - alternative to SQL Server agent jobs

Tags: sql-server, windows-services, service-broker, job-scheduling, sql-agent

I am looking for an alternative to SQL Server Agent jobs - there is a need to control running and scheduling of processes (executables, "jobs") and so I intend to implement a Windows Service that will act as a scheduler for these processes.

These processes are not interactive, so there is no problem starting them from a Windows Service, but they need to work with SQL Server - reading and writing data, executing stored procedures etc.

Commands to windows service ("scheduler") - like "enqueue a job" - would be passed from SQL Server CLR in UDF or directly from a client side web app via WCF (haven't decided yet).

Is this a right way to do this? Are there any access and security issues should I be aware of? I am particulary worried about possible limitations on processes run from a windows service.

Please share your experiences with similar designs.

Also, I consider using SQL Server Service Broker (suggested in similar thread) but I am not sure if it fits my needs.

Thank you!
Adam

Comment: This sounds like a good candidate for a Service Broker solution at first sight.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? I've searched for Service Broker uses and didn't find anything up to my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to achieve a reasonable security level is:

- create a new user that will run the Windows Service (you can create this user in Control Panel)
- create a new login for this user in SQL Server (using Integrated Security)
- give the necessary, but minimum, permissions to this user in SQL Server

To implement a service you must be aware of a few things:

- if you use WCF (or any other service stack), you need a thread for listening the requests and a different thread to run the processes in SQL server. If not, the subsequent requests will probably time out. (You can launch new threads for each task, or implement a queue to avoid overloading the server).
- be extremely careful with error (exception) handling. If an unhandled exception is thrown your service will stop, until someone starts it again
- it's harder to implement the UDF solution, becasuse you need to modify SQL Server security settings to allow an UDF to communicate with the "outer world"
- you should include some kind of logging in your service, so that you can test it and verify it's working correctly.

It's not to hard to [make an executable that can be run as console app as well as as a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764088/net-console-application-as-windows-service). If you do so you can run it from the Visual Studio debugger, or stand alone, and log in the console (`Console.Write...(...)`), to see what's going on.