# Windows service stopped after first event

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I created a windows service with a filesystemwatcher that monitor a path and fire when a text file created on the path. it works only one time and then stopped withv an unhandled error. i used try/catch but nothing happened. in event viewer it returns 1026,1000 and 1001 as eventId. it returns an error that its type is CLR20r3 and response is Not available.

Comment: Post the stacktrace/exception please.

Answer (score 0):

You can [change your app so that it can be started as console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764088/net-console-application-as-windows-service), so that it can be easily debugged from Visual Studio.

As your service is dealing with files, one of the possible problems is that the user which is runnong the service doesn't have enough permissions on the file system. You should check this. If this is the problem, the app run as console app could work perfectly, and it could fial when running as a service.