# c# - how to make my winform code to services code

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, service

How to convert my winform code to work as services in windows?

below my code

```
private BackgroundWorker worker;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();
    }


    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!worker.IsBusy)
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do some sql update query here
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET console application as Windows service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764088/net-console-application-as-windows-service)

Comment: What are you looking to do with the service? There will be no need for the BackgroundWorker in the service and if you are using a timer to run SQL periodically the best solution depends on how often the timer ticks. See [Best Timer for using in a Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246697/best-timer-for-using-in-a-windows-service)

Answer (score 0):

Services cannot interact with the user using a GUI in Windows.

I am quoting from this article: [MSDN - Interactive Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx)

> **Important**  Services cannot directly interact with a user as of Windows Vista. Therefore, the techniques mentioned in the section titled Using an Interactive Service should not be used in new code.

You need to write a console application containing all of your code which is intended to run as a service, and run that as a service.

Then you need to have a separate WinForms application for interaction with the user.

Your two applications will interact with each other using some inter-process communication mechanism, probably pipes.

Comment: yeah , i mean can i use BackgroundWorker worker and System.Timers.Timer as a windows service ?

Comment: Yes you can.  (Sorry for answering what you asked and not what you meant.)