# WireMock.Net API server is not returing data when .NET console application run as Windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, wiremock

I've started using [Wiremock.Net](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net). The setup is working fine when i run from .NET console application and below is code

```
        var server = FluentMockServer.Start(new FluentMockServerSettings
        {
            Urls = new[] { "http://+:8080", "http://localhost:8081/" },
            StartAdminInterface = true,
            ReadStaticMappings = true,
        });

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the wire mock fake server");
        Console.ReadLine();

        server.Stop();
```

The server is working fine `http://localhost:8081/__admin/mappings` and mappings are in `bin\Debug\__admin\mappings`

I want to make this console is always running and i applied same like this 
[.NET console application as Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764088/net-console-application-as-windows-service/7764451#7764451). When i start Windows Service and browse `http://localhost:8081/__admin/mappings` it just returns `[]`

Comment: Is the response you're getting coming from WireMock, or possibly a result of the firewall blocking the request? Have you tried replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Still an issue?

Answer (score 0):

See this [WireMock.Net wiki](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/wiki/WireMock-as-a-Windows-Service) page which describes how to run WireMock as a **Windows Service**.

For a full working example which also provides an *Installer* and *batch-files* to

- Install
- Start
- Stop
- Uninstall

the service, see [examples/WireMock.Net.Service](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/tree/master/examples/WireMock.Net.Service)