# Setting my java application as windows service

Tags: java, windows, service, autorun

I know that there were some of similar questions, but I would rather know how to set java application just by same application. Just more precisely I want to create program in java and send it to my fiend, after open it my application will set itself as windows service, something like hamachi, when we download, it will always run with our system. I read about java service wrapper, but I think it allows to do this from computer position, am I wrong?

Comment: you want you application to start with windows being started ????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrapp to exe with [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)

You can add service based on exe described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582108/create-windows-service-from-executable)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but what have I do now? I made windows service, but how to place it in HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run?

Comment: google it how to wrap with launch4j and google it how to add a service.  I already gave 2 links...

Answer (score 1):

I use [WinRun4J](http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/) for installing a Windows Service which starts a Java Application. It works with with 64-bit and 32-bit JVM. It is very easy to configure and install. And it's under active development and the guy gives good support. Tested it on Windows Server 2008, Windows XP, Windows 7 with Java 6 & 7 (32-bit and 64-bit)