# How to update data in ASP application after some time period?

Tags: sql, asp.net

My application have to maintain employee attendance details daily.  
In the Application, i am getting employee IN Time and OUT Time by using IN & OUT Buttons. 
The employee has to Click IN button when he enter in to office and similarly he Click on OUT button when he leaving from office in application.
By using OUT Time button click, i maintain the attendance details on that day.
My requirement:
Suppose the employee is not came to office(absent), i will not get IN&OUT details for that employee on that day.
so after some time suppose After 6 PM office closing time,the application will have search all employee IN and OUT times, then and it will automatically store(send data as Absent to database) for those employee who are absent.
How can i achieve it

Comment: Create a scheduled task, cron job, SSIS job, etc...

Comment: Easier to do this strictly in DB as @EdSF mentioned. No reason to do this in the application itself. This is a data issue.

Comment: You'll need to create an console app which will run at an scheduled time and will do the job, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739396/schedule-a-c-sharp-console-application

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Quartz.Net. It's an open source job scheduling component that you can use to fire off code at specific times. You could then use it to fire off your code that checks the db for absent employees after close of business.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/