# Golang: HTTP deployment under Windows

Tags: windows, http, go

The Go language provides handlers for serving HTTP responses. It is easy enough to start up a Go program on the command prompt, that listens for incoming HTTP requests.

What are the deployment options for running such a Go program in the background on a Windows Server machine? For example, is there a standard method for creating a Windows Service that runs the Go program in the background?

Comment: Can you not just create a service and set its target to the Go executable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Windows service from executable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582108/create-windows-service-from-executable)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, thanks for the tip. I'll try to create a service using the Sv.exe command to run the Go program

Answer (score 14):

There is an excellent golang package [kardianos/service](https://github.com/kardianos/service) that will allow you to create a service whatever the platform you are targeting.

As you can see [here](http://decouvric.cluster013.ovh.net/golang/thirdparty/divers/creer-un-service-golang-avec-kardianos.html) (it is in french but what is interesting is the code sample at the begginning of the page), it is easy to extend your program with command line options such as :

- *install* install the service.
- *remove* remove the service.
- *run* simply run the program (not as a service).
- *start/stop* the service

Comment: @EthanMick I fixed the link to an archive : http://decouvric.cluster013.ovh.net/golang/thirdparty/divers/creer-un-service-golang-avec-kardianos.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [NSSM](http://nssm.cc/) [(create service from any executable)](http://sanatgersappa.blogspot.com/2013/07/windows-service-with-go-easy-way.html)

> `nssm install MyService d:\MyService.exe`

2. Use [golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc) package

... others ...