# How to create a service running a .exe file on Windows 2012 Server?

Tags: windows, service, windows-server-2012

I have created .exe in .net and want to use as a service, run all time on my local machine. I am using windows server 2012. how to setup a service on my local computer.

**You can use windows shell script for create service with commands **

The sc create command performs the operations of the CreateService API function.

Here's what to do ...

1. copy the "yourapplication.exe " to a suitable location on your
   Win2012 server (e.g. C:\Windows\System32\ ).
2. Use "sc " to create a new service that launches "srvany " (e.g. sc
   create "Servicename" binPath= "C:'Windows'System32'srvany.exe"
   DisplayName= "My Custom Service" )
3. Using RegEdit : create a "Parameters " key for your service (e.g.
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Servicename\Paramaters)
4. Using RegEdit : within the newly created "Parameters " key , create
   a string value called "Application " and enter the full path to the
   application you are wanting to run as a service.  (No quotes
   required.)

Syntax:-

> sc [] create [] [type= {own | share | kernel | filesys | rec | interact type= {own | share}}] [start= {boot | system | auto | demand | disabled}] [error= {normal | severe | critical | ignore}] [binpath= ] [group= ] [tag= {yes | no}] [depend= ] [obj= { | }] [displayname= ] [password= ]

[More...](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc990289.aspx)

Comment: `srvany.exe` does not exist in stock Windows installations.

Comment: I just did it using [Non Sucking Service Manager](http://nssm.cc/) on Windows Server 2012 and it worked pretty fine. It does the registry foo for you.

Comment: This detailed answer helped me, it also describes how to use NSSM.exe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582108/create-windows-service-from-executable

Comment: https://download.cnet.com/SrvAny/3001-2084_4-10873628.html

Answer (score 16):

You can just do that too, it seems to work well too.
`sc create "Servicename" binPath= "Path\To\your\App.exe" DisplayName= "My Custom Service"`

You can open the registry and add a string named Description in your service's registry key to add a little more descriptive information about it. It will be shown in services.msc.

Answer (score 10):

You can use PowerShell.

```
New-Service -Name "TestService" -BinaryPathName "C:\WINDOWS\System32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs"
```

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-service?view=powershell-3.0

Comment: Additing a Description switch will make this command more useful.

New-Service -Name "TestService" -BinaryPathName "C:\WINDOWS\System32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs" -Description "Some Service Description"