# start.bat file to run a hosted game server as a background process

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a private server for Ark Survival Evolved running on my system, have a start.bat file to make it run as server, I play the game on the same machine. What im wanting to do is have it run as a background process so that I can Lock my desktop when im not that the machine, and the server will continue to run. I have Reign of kings server that will run when locked, but Ark will shut down as its running in the "Apps" in task manager in windows 8.1
I have been told to change the bat file, but im not educated in programming and not sure what coding would make this happen. any help or advice is apreciated.

Comment: Is the batch file just starting an .exe?  Please post the batch file.

Comment: See the info about NSSM at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582108/create-windows-service-from-executable.  If it can be started as a service that should do the trick, but you'll just have to try and see if it will work.

Comment: start ShooterGameServer.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\ARK\ShooterGame\ShooterGame.uproject" "/Game/Maps/TheIslandSubMaps/TheIsland?QueryPort=27015?SessionName=MY-Server?MaxPlayers=50?listen?ServerPassword=PASS?ServerAdminPassword=PASSWORD" -nosteamclient -game -server -log
exit

Comment: Thats the start bat file I have got, I have looked at the link you suggested and Im unsure where I need to add the code, at the begining or the end of the .bat?

Comment: You aren't adding code to your batch file.  Did you follow the link to NSSM?  There is usage information at http://nssm.cc/usage.  This will create a service that runs your existing batch file.  See Windows documentation or use Google if you aren't familiar with how to stop/start Windows services.