# Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion after increase time-out settings

Tags: windows, service, exe

I am trying to make .exe file service. I have created service via cmd using `sc` command. However, when I try to start it, i get problem:

> 'Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion'

Then I changed response time from 30 secs to 3 mins. After that service starting window load to 100%, but at the time it reaches 100%, again it pops up me same error:

> 'Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion'

How is it possible to solve this and run properly windows service?

Comment: Why do you think that will work? You cannot just make a service from any executable, it has to implement a ServiceMain for that to work. There are tools that can make a service from any executable, try searching. Off-topic for SO anyway.

Comment: @Soorapadman: in your past ~20 edits, you've made a couple of common mistakes: 1) don't highlight quotes as code. Use `>` instead of four spaces for quotes. The latter is for code. 2) Do not add "thanks" to posts. 3) Try to fix _all_ issues in a post, not just syntax highlighting. An easy one you seem to often skip is capitalize 'i' to 'I'. 4) Provide a useful edit reason instead of _"Question should be edit"_. Please and thank you.

Comment: CodeCaster, there was an example  with .exe so thought i would work:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582108/create-windows-service-from-executable

Comment: I have edited that answer, there were too many comments pointing that out, but nobody cared to update the answer. Read it again, then read the other answers to that question.

Comment: thank you. tried with their given NSSM , service kinda loaded as got another error on html (page not found)

Comment: Well not every executable _can_ be used as a service, for example because they require a user profile to be loaded. Anyway, still off-topic for SO. Try on SuperUser by explaining what executable exactly you're trying to convert to a service, what you do exactly (where does the HTML page come from?), and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Did another web search and finally got what works perfectly:  https://amcraharja.wordpress.com/2011/05/27/installing-dropbox-as-a-service-on-windows-server-2003-2008-x64/