# Add forever node.js script to windows autorun

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, forever

I need to be sure that my node.js script work all the time on my windows based machine. Looks like `forever` works great for that purpose. However I need to be ensured that my script still will be working after windows reboot. What should I do for that?

Comment: See here for ways to create a service -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582108/create-windows-service-from-executable

Comment: Or schedule a task: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7