# Creating a portable background process script with Python

Tags: python

I have a Python script that runs in background on Windows. It can be launched with `pythonw MyScript.pyc`

I would like to do it portable, meaning it should run on Windows machines where no Python is installed. How can I do it?

I tried [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/); it seems to work, however after launching the script it presents a CMD window. I would like it to run in background, without any visible front-ends.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency

Comment: My question is specifically about background processes. I don't see the other answers answering it.

Comment: Once you have .exe executable, you can configure it to run as a service. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582108/create-windows-service-from-executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `--noconsole` option:

```
pyinstaller --noconsole <filename>
```