# How to run debug diagnostic tool as a service

Tags: iis, debug-diagnostic-tool

Is there any way to run [debug diagnostic tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924) as a service?

I want to collect IIS/App Pool crash dump in one of our servers. However, the server logs-off users after a few minutes of inactivity, which would close the debug diagnostic tool application. Running the tool as a service, if possible, would solve this problem.

OS: Windows Server 2012 R2

IIS: 8.5

Comment: I suggest you could try to use NSSM to run the debugdiag too as the service. Details ,you could refer to this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/15719678/7609093

Comment: Thanks @BrandoZhang will look into it and get back