# How to run .exe file 24/7 even after remote desktop logout VPS

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, server, vps

how can i run an .exe file 24/7 on a windows server? 
The script needs to be started manually from a virtual desktop connection and then left it in the background. The problem is that when i close the remote desktop connection the script stops.

VPS: Microsoft Windows Server 2019 with Desktop Experience Locale English AMI provided by Amazon

Comment: Create a Windows Service out of it?

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a service: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3582179/2675670

Comment: I've installed a windows service with NSSM, but when i launch "sc.exe start mynewservicename" nothing happens

Comment: You will want to check the logs and see what's up. Here's a couple of links to check out... [NSSM cheatsheet](https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/2217fd95cf15a0324696). [Event viewer command line](https://www.windows-commandline.com/event-viewer-command-line/)