# Is it possible to make custom .exe file as service? Service fails with timeout

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I made an exe file, and i want it to be service. When i execute it - it doesnt start and fails with timeout. I tried regular exe file, tried vs code exe (why not?) and it did fail with timeout as well. What am i doing wrong?

```
sc create RomaTest binpath= "\"D:\Development\VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.32.3.exe" DisplayName= "sasd"

sc start RomaTest
```

It fails with

```
[SC] StartService: error: 1053:
```

Comment: Services are isolated & (by default) run under a limited account, so any exe with a GUI is a no-go as is anything that needs elevation/administrative privileges/triggers UAC ...

Comment: Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582108/create-windows-service-from-executable

Comment: Since Vista, Services can't interact with the desktop.  It used to be a flag for service user accounts until then.  It had far more to do with the confusion of what the "current desktop" is when multiple users are logged in at the same time.  Windows XP allowed this and also had UAC.

Comment: Thanks guys a lot for info, i supose i'll find the solution for my problem with this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Windows service from executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582108/create-windows-service-from-executable)

Comment: Services are not any old program but have to follow a bunch of rules and respond to service control messages. Normal programs should use Task Scheduler which does programs. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/services/services