# create and register windows service

Tags: windows

I am creating a Windows Service using `sc` commands with my application
    .exe file (app.exe) but after registering while starting with `sc start` the serice is not starting.

And how to give configuration file while creating a Windows Service?

After creating I am getting errors

> "[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:
>
> The service did not respond to the start or control request in a
>   timely fashion."

```
sc create servicename binpath= "path of executable"
```

Comment: You can't just register any executable as a service, it has to be implemented as a service.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582108/create-windows-service-from-executable

Comment: im bit confused now ..could you plese tell me how i can implement executalbe (.exe) as windows service

Comment: That depends on the framework and language you're using. It's trivial in .NET.

Comment: i got just an executable file which runs after invoking from command line and some configuration file written in json formate.

Comment: Then see the question linked above. The app may have a command line parameter that accepts a path to the config file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Windows service from executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582108/create-windows-service-from-executable)

Answer (score 1):

i solved the issue by using npm windows module