# Katalon Localhost Agent - Start on Windows Startup without Logging In

Tags: windows, windows-10, katalon

I have a Windows 10 Pro VM, that I want to run a Localhost Katalon Agent on.
I have it running successfully, but I would like for it to start when the computer starts.
Right now, I have it running by putting a Shortcut in the Startup folder. But this only gets triggered if someone logs into the machine.
How do I get the Agent to start when windows startup, even if no one logs in?

Comment: create autostart service and it exec your app

Comment: I gave it a try, but I don't think it is setup to run as a service. I tried the "cli-win-x64.exe", "service.bat", and "start.bat". None of them could be ran as a service.

Comment: you don't understand me. i mean - write very simply service by self - this will be your exe. and this service - exec app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Come to find out. the Katalon Agent comes with [NSSM](https://nssm.cc). I was able to use that to create a Service using these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26626771/4739712