# npm http-server as a Windows Service

Tags: node.js, windows-services, httpserver, nssm

I am using http-server to host one of my local folders:
[image]

[image]

```
http-server ./
```

As you can see I downloaded nssm.exe. I am wondering how I can make this http-server command as service so I can permanently host this folder even when computer restarts? One of the suggestions I found is to use nssm but I am not sure how I can do it. I type this in my cmd:

> nssm install httpserver

and then get:

[image]

now how to start the **http-server ./** command ? Where I should type it and how?

Also if there is easier way to do it without nssm I am open to see it.

Comment: You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582108/create-windows-service-from-executable .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it by taking the following steps:

1. Creating a batch file(script.bat) in the directory with the command:

   http-server .
2. Adding npm bin directory to environment variable for the binaries to be available from the command prompt.
3. Starting nssm.exe with the following command:

   nssm.ext install **service_name**
4. In the Path, providing the path to the batch file created in step 1.
5. In the I/O section, providing the paths to stdin, stdout and stderr to check on the output.
6. Click Install service.
7. Start the service.

Comment: Is this working for you? I mean I am not able to start the service this way.

Comment: can you give me more info on 2. Adding npm bin directory to environment variable for the binaries to be available from the command prompt. ? How to do it

Comment: 'http-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file - this is what stderr is saying

Comment: Actually this solved the step 2
Make sure the locations of both npm and http-server are added in environment variable 'PATH' (Both user variable and System variable).

If it is not present,

add C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm and C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\http-server to environment variable 'PATH'

Comment: For 2, follow the answers on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows

Comment: I added C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm to path variable and it worked for me

Comment: I agree. This is the working answer. Thank you