# How do I run a Go program as a background process?

Tags: windows, service, background-process, daemon

I'm curious, is there a way to run my Go program in the background as a `daemon` in windows?

I have a hello-world.exe on my machine, how do I run this in the background or hide the console window?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Windows service from executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582108/create-windows-service-from-executable)

Comment: As @blami stated, you can create windows service. You can check the following library to serve your application as a windows service; https://github.com/kardianos/service.

Comment: I tested it out but I get a timeout 1053 error when trying to run the service