# Start program with a Scheduled Task on startup with C#?

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I must make a new Scheduled Task to start an application on windows startup.
Just like placing it in the "Startup" folder...
But I need to create, enable and disable this task in C#.
How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set a program to launch at startup.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674628/how-do-i-set-a-program-to-launch-at-startup)

Comment: NOT the same thing. I need not to place it in the startup folder, put it in a registry or make it a Windows Service. I need a task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Task Scheduler library available on codeproject.com that might do what you need:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx

Its an older library that may or may not work with newer versions of windows.  At the very least, it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: That seems to be just what I need!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing this as a windows service.  It gives you the most control over the life cycle of a task like this.  [Here is a detailed tutorial.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)  There is also a great wizard in Visual Studio to get you going in a few minutes.

I usually like to create a debug service using the sc tool (see tutorial) that points directly to your debug object as a means of easy debugging.