# Windows 10: How to make application run on startup programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I am writing a small application for my team that will give some feedback on the current build. It is a simple .Net WPF desktop application.

The question is, how do I make this start automatically?

I could of course just instruct everyone to put a shortcut of the application in their startup folder, like this: https://www.howtogeek.com/208224/how-to-add-programs-files-and-folders-to-system-startup-in-windows-8.1/

But where is the fun in that?

Comment: Did you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674628/how-do-i-set-a-program-to-launch-at-startup

Comment: Did you try google? Because its suggests adding your app to the registry

Comment: Thanks mm8, that solved my problem!