# how to make script in python run at startup after converting it to exe by py installer

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, startup, pyinstaller

I want to make my script run on startup automatically after converting it to EXE by pyinstaller tool ,
***once clicking on SPEED.EXE 'name of program' ,It copies itself to particular path on computer then makes  a bat file  in startup folder 'it contains code to  start SPPED.EXE'
but my problem that bat file doesnot run on start ***

```
import os
import ftplib
import sys                   
import shutil                   
import getpass                
##################copy script into startup#######################
def copy_script():
    USER_NAME = getpass.getuser()
    src=sys.argv[0]
    dst = r'C:\Users\%s\AppData' % USER_NAME
    shutil.copy2(src,dst)
    dst='C:\Users\\"%s"\AppData\SPEED.exe' % USER_NAME                   ######name of script after making EXE
    add_to_startup(USER_NAME,file_path=dst)
    return None
######################################make a bat file to run on startup######
def add_to_startup(USER_NAME,file_path):
    if file_path == "":
        file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    bat_path = r'C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup' % USER_NAME
    with open(bat_path + '\\' + "open.bat", "w") as bat_file:
        bat_file.write(r'@echo off'+ os.linesep)   ## to hide console batch file when it run
        bat_file.write(r'start "" %s' % file_path)

if __name__=='__main__':
    copy_script()
    start()     ##it is  function that i make it
```

Comment: Does it start, when you execute your bat-file manualy? You are missing an `r` in front of the string in line: `dst='C:\Users\\"%s"\AppData\SPEED.exe' % USER_NAME`. Furthermore, if your bat-file does not start: delete the `@echo off`-line and start it manualy in the console to get an stderr-print

Comment: I write r but there is the same problem and when run batch file  manually ,message says"fatal error failed to execute script SPEED" and the same problem  when deleting  the @echo off

Comment: Any more details on your error? Could you may print(1,2,3, ...) between your lines to determine the line of code, where your programm is crashing? Furthermore, you should a add a check if you current location is allready the location in the Startup/Appdata-folder.

Comment: I have not errors in debugging , this error only is  shown when clicking on batch file manually

Comment: Is there any more information than "fatal error failed to execute script SPEED"? You can also try to copy your executabel directly into the startup-folder, instead of refering to it with the bat-file. Finally, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/674654/4464653).

Comment: thanks for your effort , I can solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

thanks,I could solve  my problem.

instead of creating a bat file in startup file  " I delete `add_to_startup` method " ,I used registry method

```
    import winreg;
    key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
    r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run', 0,
    winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE); winreg.SetValueEx(key, 'speed', 0,
    winreg.REG_SZ,'file_path'); # file_path is path of file after coping it
```

the error "fatal error failed to execute script SPEED " is result of the method  `shutil.copy2(src,dst)` can't copy the same source to same destination at startup so I make exception

```
        try:
            shutil.copy2(src,dst)
        except:
                pass
```