# Launch Windows Form Program on Startup

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am using below code for launch my program on startup:

```
RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
    ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

    rk.SetValue(AppName, Application.ExecutablePath);
```

but when run my project this error occourrs:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.'

Answer (score 1):

There was this issue a long time ago.

**first** you need to set registry in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` **make sure you have enough permissions!**:

```
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
        {
            key.SetValue(AppName, Application.ExecutablePath);
        }
```

Then follow the steps from this [post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674628/how-do-i-set-a-program-to-launch-at-startup)

> 1. Add it to the current user's Startup folder.  This requires the least permissions for your app to run, and gives the user the most
>      control and feedback of what's going on.  The down-side is that it's a
>      little more difficult determining whether to show the checkbox already
>      checked next time they view that screen in your program.
> 2. Add it to the `HKey_Current_User\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`
>      registry key.  The only problem here is that it requires write access
>      to the registry, which isn't always available.
> 3. Create a Scheduled Task that triggers on User Login
> 4. Add it to the `HKey_Local_Machine\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`
>      registry key.  The only problem here is that it requires write access
>      to the registry, which isn't always available.
> 5. Set it up as a windows service.  Only do this if you *really* mean it, *and* you know for sure you want to run this program for *all*
>      users on the computer.