# Working with Multiple BackGroundWorker with Different Task or Operation

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

As a .NET developer i have been working 3 C# Windows applications (database updation, crawling data, and downloading an Excel file for importing to database). I have create these 3 projects separately and these 3 application run in background and show every notification on desktop only.

My questions:

- How to run these 3 applications on single application?
- How to run my second application in background? How to start it when i shutdown and restart the system or laptop?
- My 3rd application downloads and imports. once i start it downloading and importing process is once a week or a month, so i have a date picker select today date (06/10/2018 saturday) and week option.  How to continue when i shutdown and restart my system?
- How to continue  where it stopped after i shutdown or restart my application?
- These 3 applications are running on internet. How to pause and and run when internet available only?
- How to show windows form applications notification on web application?

Comment: Your language makes it very difficult to understand the questions. For example, what is "running 3 applications as 1 application"? If you have built he applications, aren't you the expert who knows that?

Comment: Tried to make sense of the questions. You really should not ask all of them in same question. Before asking, you should use google, read & watch tutorials etc.

Answer (score 0):

- First: Yes it is possible, do it on 3 separate threads in one process (application). [More here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/threading/)
- Second: Simply [Start application on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674628/how-do-i-set-a-program-to-launch-at-startup) and i would implement in my application code to see if there is one more instance of application running and if it is i would close this one.
- Third: Store next download date in some database or txt file. On application start check `if(nextDownloadDate > today) //Which mean it should have been updated` and if it is true update what you need and update `next download date`. This way if you turn off your pc (app) and you startup pc again (automatically run app) it will check if it should have been updated and if it is it will do the job
- Fourth: Too broad. Try googling or thinking about way of storing data in database/txt/xmal each time you make step and again on application run check from that files where you have stopped
- Google it. Not that hard. "How to check if computer have internet access".
- Too broad. Think yourself.

Few items i haven't answered since this question is too broad and should be closed but since i see you are new one i made some advises up there for you.