# how to Start exe with elevated rights when domain user logs in

Tags: c#, windows-10

I need to start a windows forms application with admin rights whenever a domain user logs in.
I am trying to start the application with service and task scheduler but the application UI does not show up. However I can see it running in the task manager. and if I add a timer and terminate the app. it terminates after correct interval as well.

Can someone help me on how to develop/deploy an application so that it shows "the UI" when whenever any user logs in to the machine. should I add some registry entry that will start me application or is there any other way to achieve this..

Comment: "*trying to start the application with service*" - this is the wrong approach. Use a group policy

Answer (score 0):

To check if user has logged in into a domain, you can use

`System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Name` which gives you `"domain\username"`.

and for starting your application once user logged in, you have to run your program at start up, try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674628/how-do-i-set-a-program-to-launch-at-startup).

And to run your app at startup using group policy (recommended) try [this](https://tekbloq.com/2016/08/12/how-to-run-programs-automatically-when-a-user-logs-on-with-gpo/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that when the user logs in, the task does not really work because there are not enough rights. Try it like this:
you need to create a new task that simply launches the program you want to use without UAC dialogs. When creating this task, in the General tab, enter the name of the task (remember this name, you will need it later) and check the box that says “Run with highest privileges - Run with highest privileges”. This puts the task to run with administrator rights.
To make sure there are no compatibility issues, go to the “Configure for” drop-down list at the bottom of the Create Task window and select Windows ® 7, Windows Server ™ 2008 R2.
On the Actions tab - Actions, you need to create an action that launches the program. Everything is very simple here: select the action “Start a program”, specify the path to the program that will be executed, and click OK.

Your last stop is on the Settings tab. Here you need to make sure that the checkbox “Allow task to be run on demand” is checked. Also, make sure that when the task is already running, another instance will not be started by choosing the option “Do not start a new instance”
The second step in this procedure is to create a shortcut that launches the task you just created, which in turn launches the program of your choice without the UAC line appearing.
An important difference when creating a shortcut to a task compared to a normal shortcut on the desktop is to enter schtasks / run / tn Task Name - Schtasks / run / tn “Task Name” (Task Name must be replaced with the actual task name) in the Item Location field. In this command, the / Run parameter simply performs a specific task, and / tn allows you to enter the name of the task you want to run.
Once the shortcut is created, if you click on it, it will work like the task you created, and this in turn launches the program specified with administrator rights, but without UAC.
Thus, you can create a task to run the created shortcut.